Submitting HTML form using JavaScript
I have a simple HTML form for which I use Javascript to submit the form. But when I run the code the result is a 404 error or I don't go to link address. I am aiming to submit to https://google.com?type=type in this example.
JS Fiddle code here


var url = 'https://google.com'
var query = document.querySelector('form').getAttribute('action');
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  fetch(`${url}/${query}`, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: new URLSearchParams(new FormData(event.target))
  }).then(this.reset.bind(this));
});
<form action="?type=type">
  <input type="email" name="SENDER" placeholder="Your email" required="required" />
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name" required="required" />
  <textarea name="message" cols="30" rows="5" required="required"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>




Sorry JavaScript

Google does not support CORS, nor does it accept POST requests. You cannot make an async request to it

Are you trying to “submit the form” or “go to link address”? What exactly did you expect to happen? What’s the significance of the URL in question, exactly?

Are you trying to submit a form to a different domain? Read about CORS - domains have to allow your website to send requests to them. If you just want to test your code, install a webserver and send the request to localhost.
